# How to extract a specific value from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to extract distance from google distance matrix API in Python. The objet it returned is a python dictionary.

```
{
    'destination_addresses': [Mumbai, Maharashtra, India '],
        'origin_addresses': ['Powai, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India'],
        'rows': [{
            'elements': [{
                'distance': {
                    'text': u '47.1 km',
                    'value': 47086
                },
                'duration': {
                    'text': '1 hour 17 mins',
                    'value': 4628
                },
                'status': 'OK'
            }]
        }],
        'status': 'OK'
    }
```

I want to extract the distance and duration from above. I have used

```
distance = my_distance["rows"]
for a in distance:
    result = a["elements"]
    print result
```

It gave me

```
[{
    u 'duration': {
        u 'text': u '1 hour 17 mins', u 'value': 4628
    }, u 'distance': {
        u 'text': u '47.1 km', u 'value': 47086
    }, u 'status': u 'OK'
}]
```

Now how to extract duration (1 hour 17 mins) and distance (47.1 km) and their corresponding values (4628 & 47086)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply do it as:

```
print "time taken : ", d["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["duration"]["text"]
print "distance : ", d["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["text"]
print "distance value : ", d["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"]
print "duration value : ", d["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["duration"]["value"]
```

Answer (score -1):

`a["elements"]` contains a list of dictionaries. You can either iterate over it or fetch values by the index value. You can try this in the `for` loop:

```
distance = result[0]['text']
duration = result[1]['text']
```