# How do i access the value of subject_id in the following dictionary in python

Tags: python

How do i access the value of `subject_id` in the following dictionary in python

```
recognized_faces={'images': [{'candidates':[{'confidence': 0.93778,
                        'enrollment_timestamp':'1515258270583',
                        'face_id': '5a51019de4f0a8539156',
                        'subject_id': 'abc'}],
                  'transaction': {'confidence': 0.93778,
                                  'eyeDistance': 157,
                                  'face_id': 1,
                                  'gallery_name': 'a-gallery',
                                  'height': 370,
                                  'quality': 1.39258,
                                  'status': 'success',
                                  'subject_id': 'abc',
                                  'topLeftX': 277,
                                  'topLeftY': 284,
                                  'width': 370}}]}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: done formatting the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a specific value from a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970333/how-to-extract-a-specific-value-from-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access values in your dictionary like so, where `obj` is your object:

```
recognized_faces= {'images': [{'candidates':[{'confidence': 0.93778,
                        'enrollment_timestamp':'1515258270583',
                        'face_id': '5a51019de4f0a8539156',
                        'subject_id': 'abc'}],
             'transaction': {'confidence': 0.93778,
                             'eyeDistance': 157,
                             'face_id': 1,
                             'gallery_name': 'a-gallery',
                             'height': 370,
                             'quality': 1.39258,
                             'status': 'success',
                             'subject_id': 'abc',
                             'topLeftX': 277,
                             'topLeftY': 284,
                             'width': 370}}]}

images = recognized_faces['images']
for image in images:
    for candidate in image['candidates']:
        print(candidate['subject_id'])
```

Note that this has no error checking, and if a key does not exist will throw errors.

Comment: it shows the following error:                                                                          
for candidate in image['candidates']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Worked for me for your original object, by the way when you updated your code, you have an invalid object now. Remove the final `}`

Comment: Chris, i've updated the code again, can you please check again

Comment: It still works for me. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: python 3.6 chrisz

Comment: I tested my answer on 3.6, and it ran.

Comment: Chrisz it worked, thanks a ton!!, really appreciate your help.

Comment: If it answered your question, please accept as an answer.